# RecyclerView with custom shaped items

Tags: android, canvas, android-recyclerview, imageview, shapes

I created a custom shaped imageview. It works fine if you use it in scrollview. But when i tried to use it in a recyclerview there's a strange behavior i observed. Images are not getting draw and show gap (see 1st image) unless you scroll down (see 2nd image). Same thing happens when you scroll up.

I want to know how to avoid these gaps. Could you please point me where i am doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Initial state or after scrolling up:

[image: Initial state]

After scrolling down:

[image: After scrolling down]

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 * Created by santalu on 7/4/17.
 */

public class DiagonalImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public static final int TOP = 0;
    public static final int MIDDLE = 1;
    public static final int BOTTOM = 2;

    private final Path mClipPath = new Path();
    private final Path mLinePath = new Path();

    private final Paint mLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    private int mPosition;
    private int mOverlap;
    private int mLineColor;
    private int mLineSize;

    private boolean mMaskEnabled = true;

    public DiagonalImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public DiagonalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs == null) {
            return;
        }

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ShowCaseImageView);
        try {
            mPosition = a.getInt(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_position, TOP);
            mOverlap = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_overlap, 0);
            mLineSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_lineSize, 0);
            mLineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_lineColor, Color.BLACK);

            mLinePaint.setColor(mLineColor);
            mLinePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            mLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineSize);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void setPosition(int position, boolean maskEnabled) {
        mMaskEnabled = maskEnabled;
        setPosition(position);
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        if (mPosition != position) {
            mClipPath.reset();
            mLinePath.reset();
        }
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int saveCount = canvas.getSaveCount();
        canvas.clipPath(mClipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mLinePath, mLinePaint);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
    }

    @Override protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (!changed) {
            return;
        }

        if (mMaskEnabled && mClipPath.isEmpty()) {
            int width = getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = getMeasuredHeight();

            if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            switch (mPosition) {
                case TOP:
                    mClipPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(width, height - mOverlap);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);

                    mLinePath.moveTo(0, height);
                    mLinePath.lineTo(width, height - mOverlap);
                    break;
                case MIDDLE:
                    mClipPath.moveTo(0, mOverlap);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(width, height - mOverlap);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);

                    mLinePath.moveTo(0, height);
                    mLinePath.lineTo(width, height - mOverlap);
                    break;
                case BOTTOM:
                    mClipPath.moveTo(0, mOverlap);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(width, height);
                    mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);
                    break;
            }
            mClipPath.close();
            mLinePath.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I include the sample app here to demonstrate the issue if you are interested

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.santalu.showcaseimageview.ShowCaseImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int overlap = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.overlap_size);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new OverlapItemDecoration(-overlap));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter(this));
    }

    static class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private final Context mContext;

        SampleAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(position);
        }

        @Override public int getItemCount() {
            return 7;
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            DiagonalImageView image;
            //int overlap;

            ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                image = (DiagonalImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                //overlap = -mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.overlap_size);
            }

            void bind(int position) {
                boolean maskEnabled = getItemCount() > 1;
                //MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
                if (position == 0) {
                    image.setPosition(ShowCaseImageView.TOP, maskEnabled);
                    //params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                } else if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
                    image.setPosition(ShowCaseImageView.BOTTOM, maskEnabled);
                    //params.setMargins(0, overlap, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    image.setPosition(ShowCaseImageView.MIDDLE, maskEnabled);
                    //params.setMargins(0, overlap, 0, 0);
                }
                //image.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
    }

    static class OverlapItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private int mOverlap;

        OverlapItemDecoration(int overlap) {
            mOverlap = overlap;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
            if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) != 0) {
                outRect.top = mOverlap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.santalu.diagonalimageview.DiagonalImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/demo"
    app:csi_lineColor="@color/deep_orange"
    app:csi_lineSize="@dimen/line_size"
    app:csi_overlap="@dimen/overlap_size"/>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research and try i figured out that **Path** values aren't correct and well designed especially for border. 
Some cases they are overlapping each other and i thought this causes images not drawn correctly.

I redesigned the view and made some improvements. For future readers here's final code:

```
/**
 * Created by santalu on 7/4/17.
 *
 * Note: if position set NONE mask won't be applied
 *
 * POSITION    DIRECTION
 *
 * TOP         LEFT |  RIGHT
 * BOTTOM      LEFT |  RIGHT
 * LEFT        TOP  |  BOTTOM
 * RIGHT       TOP  |  BOTTOM
 */

public class DiagonalImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private static final String TAG = DiagonalImageView.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int NONE = 0;
    public static final int TOP = 1;
    public static final int RIGHT = 2;
    public static final int BOTTOM = 4;
    public static final int LEFT = 8;

    private final Path mClipPath = new Path();
    private final Path mBorderPath = new Path();

    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    private int mPosition;
    private int mDirection;
    private int mOverlap;
    private int mBorderColor;
    private int mBorderSize;

    private boolean mBorderEnabled;

    public DiagonalImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public DiagonalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs == null) {
            return;
        }

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DiagonalImageView);
        try {
            mPosition = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_position, NONE);
            mDirection = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_direction, RIGHT);
            mOverlap = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_overlap, 0);
            mBorderSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_borderSize, 0);
            mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_borderColor, Color.BLACK);
            mBorderEnabled = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.DiagonalImageView_di_borderEnabled, false);

            mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
            mBorderPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderSize);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void set(int position, int direction) {
        if (mPosition != position || mDirection != direction) {
            mClipPath.reset();
            mBorderPath.reset();
        }
        mPosition = position;
        mDirection = direction;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        if (mPosition != position) {
            mClipPath.reset();
            mBorderPath.reset();
        }
        mPosition = position;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setDirection(int direction) {
        if (mDirection != direction) {
            mClipPath.reset();
            mBorderPath.reset();
        }
        mDirection = direction;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mBorderEnabled = enabled;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mClipPath.isEmpty()) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            return;
        }

        int saveCount = canvas.save();
        canvas.clipPath(mClipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (!mBorderPath.isEmpty()) {
            canvas.drawPath(mBorderPath, mBorderPaint);
        }
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
    }

    @Override protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (!changed) {
            return;
        }

        if (mClipPath.isEmpty()) {
            int width = getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = getMeasuredHeight();

            if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            mClipPath.reset();
            mBorderPath.reset();

            switch (mPosition) {
                case TOP:
                    if (mDirection == LEFT) {
                        mClipPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, mOverlap);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, height);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);

                        if (mBorderEnabled) {
                            mBorderPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                            mBorderPath.lineTo(width, mOverlap);
                        }
                    } else {
                        mClipPath.moveTo(0, mOverlap);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, height);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);

                        if (mBorderEnabled) {
                            mBorderPath.moveTo(0, mOverlap);
                            mBorderPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    if (mDirection == TOP) {
                        mClipPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width - mOverlap, height);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);

                        if (mBorderEnabled) {
                            mBorderPath.moveTo(width, 0);
                            mBorderPath.lineTo(width - mOverlap, height);
                        }
                    } else {
                        mClipPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width - mOverlap, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, height);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);

                        if (mBorderEnabled) {
                            mBorderPath.moveTo(width - mOverlap, 0);
                            mBorderPath.lineTo(width, height);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case BOTTOM:
                    if (mDirection == LEFT) {
                        mClipPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, height - mOverlap);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);

                        if (mBorderEnabled) {
                            mBorderPath.moveTo(0, height);
                            mBorderPath.lineTo(width, height - mOverlap);
                        }
                    } else {
                        mClipPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, height);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(0, height - mOverlap);

                        if (mBorderEnabled) {
                            mBorderPath.moveTo(0, height - mOverlap);
                            mBorderPath.lineTo(width, height);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    if (mDirection == TOP) {
                        mClipPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, height);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(mOverlap, height);

                        if (mBorderEnabled) {
                            mBorderPath.moveTo(0, 0);
                            mBorderPath.lineTo(mOverlap, height);
                        }
                    } else {
                        mClipPath.moveTo(mOverlap, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(width, height);
                        mClipPath.lineTo(0, height);

                        if (mBorderEnabled) {
                            mBorderPath.moveTo(mOverlap, 0);
                            mBorderPath.lineTo(0, height);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            mClipPath.close();
            mBorderPath.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I published this on Github as a library in case you need it
[Diagonal ImageView](https://github.com/santalu/diagonal-imageview)

Answer (score 1):

you should use cut layout for row item XMl here is link https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout

```
<com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:diagonal_angle="20"
    app:diagonal_position="top"
    app:diagonal_direction="right">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/mountains" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah I'm aware of this library. But as you can see from screenshot i provided recyclerview items are overlapping each other and all items have their own divider (the orange line). And the imageview's clip path and divider path calculated by overlap height not the angle to make sure each items respect their boundraries and drawn correctly. I just want to know what's wrong with my view or recyclerview implementation. But thanks for suggestion

Comment: Besides same problem occurs with this library too. Try using it in recyclerview.

Comment: did you set diagonal position , in XML is should be like this diagonal:diagonal_position="bottom". I'm not sure but if you check last index than you can use different layout for it where in which diagonal position is set to bottom.

Comment: you can use different layout  and you can work with same layout but you can work with the visibility  of layout and use it at last index .

Comment: you have library than you can set diagonal property at last index from adapter class.

Comment: Yes i define position. I use it as library suggested. Its a shame you can't set this attributes programmatically(position,direction etc) so you have to define different xml files for this. With using different view types regarding to view position in adapter we can somehow achieve what i wanted here. But like i said earlier. We also need to create a border and somehow calculate the gap size to adjust item overlap(negative top margins). Anyways like i said in my previous comment i just want to know what the issue with my own implementation. Thanks for the help again.